# Flask form not validating on submit

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm trying to make a form that looks like an exam page. I have a checkbox and a submit button, the submit button when clicked does not do anything.

The HTML code in exam.html

```html
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h3 class="pt-5 p-4">exam page</h3>

    <div class="form">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <form method="POST" action="/" class="m-3">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">question will here</legend>
                
                <ul class="form-group">
                {{ form.optA.label(class="form-text mt-3") }}
                {{ form.optA(class="mx-2 optionA mt-3") }}
                </ul>

            </form>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="form-group m-3">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
        </div>
        
    </div>



{% endblock %}
```

My python code in app.py

```py
from flask import render_template, url_for, redirect, request
from flask import Flask
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField, BooleanField

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'

class Question(FlaskForm):
    optA = BooleanField('option A')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/exam', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def exam():
    form = Question()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("w")

    print(form.errors)        

    return render_template('exam.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The code inside `if form.validate_on_submit()` does not run when I press the submit button. When I attempted to print any errors using `form.errors`, it returned an empty dict.

Comment: You have set `action="/"` so the form is not being submitted to `/exam`. `<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('exam') }}" class="m-3">`

Comment: @roganjosh It didn't work.. Edit: same error as before

Comment: That's not particularly helpful to me. What didn't work? Did you get an error?

Comment: @roganjosh No error, same as before

Comment: It's been a long time since I used `flask-wtf`. However, `{{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}` is outside of the `<form>` tag. Does it make a difference if it's enclosed in the block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two errors:

- The action URL was wrong, not pointing at the right method
- Submit button was outside the form

Here is corrected code:

```
{% block content %}
    <h3 class="pt-5 p-4">exam page</h3>

    <div class="form">
        <form method="POST" action="/exam" class="m-3">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">question will here</legend>
                
                <ul class="form-group">
                {{ form.optA.label(class="form-text mt-3") }}
                {{ form.optA(class="mx-2 optionA mt-3") }}
                </ul>

                <div class="form-group m-3">
                    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please can you use `url_for` in the form `action`? It would also be helpful to explain the things you changed